# The case of the lone witness

Tags: beit-din-court, lashon-hara-slander, edim-witnesses

The Talmud says:

> The Holy One, Blessed be He, hates... one who observes a licentious matter performed by another person and testifies against him alone.

> [There was an] incident where Tuveya sinned... and Zigud came alone to testify about him before Rav Pappa. Rav Pappa instructed that Zigud be lashed. Zigud said to him: "Tuveya sinned and Zigud is lashed!"...  He said to him: "Yes, as it is written: “One witness shall not rise up against a man” (Deuteronomy 19:15), and you testified against him alone. You have merely given him a bad reputation." [Pesachim 113b]

But the judges presumably *know* if a witness is the only witness.  Do they *have* to ask for his testimony and listen to him?

The Shulchan Arukh only says:

> [One is] is obligated to testify *if he is called to testify in court*. [Shulchan Arukh, Choshen Mishpat 28:1]